# How can I customize the error message with localizedDescription?

Tags: swift, xcode, customization, message

I have created a login and sign up page for my app. Everything is running smoothly, but I want to be able to customize the error messages when the user enters an incorrect email address or password. This is my code right now:

```
            // Signing in the user
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

                if error != nil {

                    // Couldn't sign in
                    self.loginErrorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                    self.loginErrorLabel.alpha = 1
                }
                else {

                    let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController

                    self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
                    self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                }
            }
```

When a user enters a non-existant/incorrect email or password, an error label appears, saying "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password."

Instead, I want it to return with: "The username or password you entered is incorrect."
Is there a way to do this without completely changing the code, such as just adding some code beforehand to indicate what localizedDescription is? All help is welcome, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
 let userInformation = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "your error message"]
 let error = NSError(domain: "your domain", code: 401, userInfo:userInformation)
```

now you can use that error with "localizedDescription" or as "Error"

Comment: should i put that above the: self.loginErrorLabel.text = error.localizedDescription ? Also, where can I find my domain?

Comment: yes you can put and you find your domain in API URL or you can add any string in your domain.

Comment: @BriannaHo is the answer is what you looking for if yes then make it right so it's help other